# Unary ++ order of precedence

Tags: c, unary-operator

If `int x=5;`I suppose the expression `y=++x * ++x;` is evaluated as:

First execute `++x` causing `x=6` and then again `++x` causing `x=7` the expression then evaluates `y=x*x` making the value of `y=49`
Using same reasoning the following lines of code

```
int z=5, x=5,y=0,p=0;
y=++x * ++x + ++x;
p= ++z + ++z * ++z;
```

should have evaluated same values of `y` and `p` but the compiler produces different answer. I probably there is something I am missing in the order of precedence.

Comment: You should **never code `++x * ++x`** because that is **undefined bhavior** and the implementation is allowed to do anything (including exploding the computer, or even doing what you was naively expecting)

Answer (score 3):

Both of your expressions cause undefined behaviour by trying to modify a value more than once without an intervening sequence point.  There is no general answer to your question.

Comment: why should the compiler produce same set of consistent results on every compilation then? There can't be anything random, physics prevents that!

Comment: @PrakashGautam "Even compiler producing same set of consistent results for an undefined behaviour" is also undefined behaviour !!

Comment: @PrakashGautam Nobody said the result will be random, it can be anything - that's what "undefined behaviour" means